# Not able to start/delete/stop/click/hover GCP instance just after creating one

Tags: google-cloud-platform, instance

[From the GCP page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVsBV.png)

After I created an instance, I wasn't able to open the instance. Getting the below mentioned error :

```
e2 instances do not support onHostMaintenance=TERMINATE unless they are preemptible.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your instance as preemptible.

Create a new instance template, while creating  it, set in the  "Availability policies" section the "Preemptibility" field as "off" and "On host maintenance" as "Terminate VM instance" (consider that the "Migrate VM instance" is the recommended option) as per your choice.
Create a new instance from this newly created template. See if now you can open your new instance.

If the problem persists, you should create a case in [Google Cloud Platform support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/) to perform a deeper inspection and discard possible ongoing issues with your VM instances.